# pcregrep or grep: searching with lookaheads not working

Tags: regex, grep, pcregrep

I am trying to search for a regex with lookahead its not working in pcregrep or grep

I want to search for bits of sections

- which may span over multiple lines,
- which start with PQXY at the beginning of a line and
- end with OFEJ at the end of the line and
- does not contain either PQXY or OFEJ in between

Generall i use the following in sublime text find and works well

```
(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)
```

Now i want to find the count of such occurences so i am trying to use grep or pcergrep, both are not working.

```
pcregrep -c "(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)" file.txt
zsh: event not found: PQXY|OFEJ).)
```

and with grep

```
$ grep -c -zoP "(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJTRANS).)*OFEJTRANS\n)" CB_raw_testing_21_feb_CORRECTIONS_0002.txt
zsh: event not found: PQXY|OFEJTRANS).)
```

How can i do this

**Answer based on @paxdiablo and @anubha.**

The main error was the single quotes as addressed by @paxdiablo

```
$ pcregrep -c -M '(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)' file.txt 
0
```

The regex solution is to add (?s) based on @anubha. Ofcourse `\n` also works instead of `(\R|\z)`

```
$ pcregrep -c -M '(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)' file.txt
11726
```

Comment: Just fyi `\n` won't work if file doesn't end with a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `zsh: event not found: PQXY|OFEJ).)`

Since this is `zsh` raising the error, it's almost *certainly* because it's trying to process the stuff within the double quotes. To protect it from that, you should use *single* quotes, such as:

```
pcregrep -c '(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)' file.txt
```

I don't have `pcregrep` installed but here's a transcript showing the problem with just `echo`:

```
pax> echo "(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ)"
zsh: event not found: PQXY|OFEJ).)

pax> echo '(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?OFEJ)'
(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?OFEJ)
```

In terms of solving the *problem* rather than using a specific *tool,* I would actually opt for `awk`<sup>(a)</sup> in this case. You can do something like:

```
awk '/^PQXY/     { s = $0; c = 1; next}
     /OFEJ$/     { if (c == 1) { print s""ORS""$0; c = 0 }; next }
     /OFEJ|PQXY/ { c = 0; next }
     c == 1      { s = s""ORS""$0 }' inputFile
```

This works by using a string and flag to control lines collected and state, initially they are an empty string and zero.

Then, for each line:

- If it starts with PQXY, store the line and set the collection flag, then go to next input line.
- Otherwise, if it ends with `OFEJ` and you're collecting, output the collected section and stop collecting, then go to next input line.
- Otherwise, if it has either of the strings in it, stop collecting, move to next input line.
- Otherwise, if collecting, append current line and move (implicitly) to next input line.

I've tested this with some limited test data and it seems to work okay. Here's the `bash` script<sup>(b)</sup> I used for testing, you can add as many test cases as you need to be comfortable it solves your problem.

```
for i in \
    "PQXY 1\nabc\n2 OFEJ\n" \
    "PQXY 1\nabc\n2 OFEJx\n" \
    "PQXY 1\nabc\n  PQXY \n2 OFEJ\n" \
    "PQXY 1\nabc\n  OFEJ \n2 OFEJ\n" \
    "PQXY 1\nabc\ndef\nPQXY 2\n2 OFEJ\n" \
; do
    echo "$i:"
    printf "$i" | awk '
        /^PQXY/     { s = $0; c = 1; next}
        /OFEJ$/     { if (c == 1) { print s""ORS""$0; c = 0 }; next }
        /OFEJ|PQXY/ { c = 0; next }
        c == 1      { s = s""ORS""$0 }' | sed 's/^/    /
    '
done
```

Here's the output so you can see it in action:

```
PQXY 1\nabc\n2 OFEJ\n:
    PQXY 1
    abc
    2 OFEJ
PQXY 1\nabc\n2 OFEJx\n:
PQXY 1\nabc\n  PQXY \n2 OFEJ\n:
PQXY 1\nabc\n  OFEJ \n2 OFEJ\n:
PQXY 1\nabc\ndef\nPQXY 2\n2 OFEJ\n:
    PQXY 2
    2 OFEJ
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In my experience, if you've tried three things with a `grep`-style regex without success, it's usually faster to move to a more advanced tool :-)

---

<sup>(b)</sup> Yes, I know it's written in `bash` rather than `zsh` but that's because:

- it's a *test* program to show you that `awk` works, hence the language used is irrelevant; and
- I'm far more comfortable with `bash` tahn `zsh` :-)

Comment: It solves the error. But the count is shown zero. Its not correct. Can you check the updated question

Comment: @Santhosh, the regex being wrong is a *different* issue, unrelated to the error you got. You should generally ask *one* question per question and, if there are more problems, ask another question. That both keeps questions and answers compatible and better targets specific problems for people searching in future.

Comment: you anwered the main question. the regex part should be another question

Comment: thanks for the awk solution. I love to do things with awk but only because of lookaheads i use perl

Comment: thanks for showing with a sample data how to use the awk.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu grep`:

```
grep -ozP '(?ms)^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ(\R|\z)' file
```

- You must use `-z` option to treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte.
- Make sure to use single quotes for your pattern so that shell's history module doesn't attempt to process `!`.
- Added `(?m)` (MULTILINE) modifier to allow use of `^` and `$` in regex for each line
- Used `(\R|\z)` to allow ending pattern to end without newline at the end of file. `\R` matches any ind of line break including unicode characters and `\z` matches end of input.

[Working Demo](https://ideone.com/lAKMJi)

---

Equivalent solution in `pcregrep`

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ(\R|\z)' file
```

`-M` enables multiline optio in `pcregrep`.

Comment: It solves the error but shows wrong results. The `(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)` is not working

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: I have added a working demo of above solution https://ideone.com/lAKMJi

Comment: Yes the pcregrep command works as per your answer. I updated the question with what  is working for me. But grep is not working

Comment: I am checking it some sample text

Comment: Since your main question of `event not found` got answered, I suggest you post a different question to solve secondary problem :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hUbce498 (this is a sample text). Checked with `grep -c -zoP '(?ms)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ(\R|\z))' test.txt` it shows `1`, whereas with `pcregrep -c -M '(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)' test.txt` it shows correct result `2`

Comment: Here i am still using the same regex `(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)` which i used for my sublime text. In the question i was not able to show that i already tried  `pcregrep -c -M "(?s)(^PQXY(?:(?!PQXY|OFEJ).)*OFEJ\n)" test.txt` but failed due to double quotes. So the double quotes confused me that i am not using the right regex. When you showed its working for you then i got the faith back. But for grep its not working

Comment: I have already shown in a demo that is working fine and since you've accepted other answer without solving your actual problem there is no point in having extended discussion in comments section. I suggest you use proposed awk solution.